# Increase font size in Google search results

Tags: google-search, text-formatting

Can I increase the font size in Google search results? I already searched everywhere, but still didn't get an answer

Comment: Have you tried zooming in? This is the behavior you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

All browsers have the ability to zoom in and out. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> are the usual keyboard commands.

Answer (score 0):

If zooming does not fit your needs You can try any solution to manipulate DOM i.e. to insert "tweak" into the page:

- change CSS
- use javascript / jquery

there are a lot of add-ons for browsers.

Example - for Title you need to tweak

`<h3 class="r">`

Answer (score 0):

you can use **Zoom Text Only** extension for this task:

- add/install it from **[https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/zoom-text-only/jamhfhbppcmkgghlkeieococonlbppjg)**
- visit **[https://www.google.com/search?](https://www.google.com/search?num=30&newwindow=1&hl=en&ei=ZqtGW5uHFJGVsAerp7PIDA&q=*)**
- edit font size as shown below

[image]

or you can try **Zoom on double-click** extension:

- add/install it from **[https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/zoom-on-doubleclick/jkmalmidnicnnmceielaelokkdmmgkcb/related)**
- visit any site
- double-click on the area where you need the zoom
- and double-click again to reverse back

[image]